# Allowing remote connections to MySQL in Ubuntu Server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-server

I am experiencing some difficulties to configure MySQL Server and allow remote connections. I am currently using Ubuntu Server 16.04 and the latest MySQL version. This is a Virtual Private Server (VPS) from VpsDime (I apologize if this is not relevant). Everything i have done has been accomplished by SSH protocol using the root user.

This is the error Workbench throws me when I try to connect to MySQL:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'globalAdmin' from your host server at <IP>:3306:
Can't connect to MySQL server on '<ServerIP>' (10060).
```

I have been following and reading tutorials to configure it at this point. So, the relevant things i have done for this are:

Install the latest version of MySQL
Create a user granting full privileges for local and outsiders by this way:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

I modified the MySQL configuration file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf using nano. The change i made was replacing this:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

For this:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

This is to allow remote connections, this was suppose to be done in my.cnf file, but i modified another file based on the first answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/699903/why-is-etc-mysql-my-cnf-empty

Also i added the following two lines in my  file.

```
[mysqld]    
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Finally, using UFW I am allowing the port 3306 and 3306/tcp. Using the command sudo ufw status I am getting this (i am showing only the relevant):

```
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Which as far I know is all I need to connect remotely.
The way I am connecting to MysQL server is by MySQLWorkbench for Windows, Connection Method: Standard(TCP/IP) using my server ip address, default port (3306), the "globaAdmin" user I created as  mentioned before without Schema.

**---The following MAY NOT be relevant---**

Im having the same issue for MongoDB, it is funny because I also installed MS SQL Server 2017 and the only thing i did to connect remotely was open ports for it with the UFW tool.

Comment: Do you have a globalAdmin user with correct any host privilege?

Comment: Yes, I did: GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'globalAdmin'@'%';